# Changing font recognition for tesseract in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, image-processing, tesseract

I am using Tesseract 3.0 in order to read digits from a seven segment display but that did not work properly. 
I assume the reason of that is the font of the seven segment display which is different from the usual one that is read. 
I was wondering if there was a way to change the font so that the results are compatible with the digits found on the 7 segment display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To optimize for certain fonts you can either [train tesseract for a certain font](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3)  or customize the scanning method.
There's really no telling which will be quicker without more details of the font and the environment you are sampling from.